# How to make discord bot execute code on a given day of month

Tags: python, datetime, discord, discord.py

I want my bot to send out a message on a certain day each month in this case the 1st.

In the following code, I just use a while loop to see if it is the day and if not just repeat until it is, however, in this case, it will be stuck in the loop and the bot won´t start. I am also pretty sure if I do this it will only work once. How do I make some code run on someday of the month without it being stuck in a loop and working every month in a discord bot?

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import timevaribels
from datetime import datetime

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '/')

channel_id = 852604482637398056

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('ready')

async def annoucment():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    channel = client.get_channel(channel_id)
    while datetime.now() != timevaribels.custom_date_time:
      pass
    else:
        await channel.send('message')

async def backround():
    await annoucment()

client.loop.create_task(backround())
client.run('key')
```

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/schedule/

Comment: @Goion ti looks like you cant run this on a certain day of the month the maximum is every day of the week, this might work though

Comment: It definitely can. Go through the documentation. https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html#run-a-job-until-a-certain-time

Comment: The schedule library is blocking, you shouldn’t use it within asynchronous code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the tasks of discord.ext!

Example:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from datetime import datetime

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '/')

channel_id = 852604482637398056
targetDate = '06-11' # month / day

def GetDate():
    return datetime.today().strftime('%m-%d')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    # I recommend put this on construtor
    DateChecker.start() # Start the loop 
    print('Ready')

@tasks.loop(hours=24)
async def DateChecker():
    print("Running loop...")

    if GetDate() == targetDate:
        channel = client.get_channel(channel_id) 
        await channel.send("Hello World!")

client.run('key')
```

See https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html

Comment: for the target date variable would '%m - 1' work? or can it only be a specific day of the year

Comment: Of course, you can set the day, month or year. You only need change the GetDate datetime object (%y, %m or %d) and targetDate.